# Periodically Delete MySQL Table A Rows but keep the associated table B data which gets updated based on as per data of table A

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

I have two Tables Table A and Table B.. Table A stores data on every page load where Table B get's updated based on the data of Table A. Now, i want to delete Table A rows after specific time period but keep the data in Table B as it is which becomes zero after the removal of Table A rows.

My Table A have UserIP column where Table B gets updated by the count of Unique IP addresses and count of Rows in table A. Let's say there are 10 Unique IP and 120 Rows in Table A so Table B will show the count 120 and  10 in it's column fields. Now I want to delete table A rows after specified time but keep the data of Table B fields as they were before deletion that is 120 and 10 and continue the count as per previous data like new row in table A will be counted and 121 in Table B and New IP address will be counted as 11 in Table B.

Any suggestions OR help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after searching here and there i found that my problem can be solved using MySQL’s Event Scheduler. Following article helped me to get right answer and code.. Hope it can help others as well..

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

Answer (score 0):

> Now, i want to delete Table A rows after specific time period but keep
>   the data in Table B as it is which becomes zero after the removal of
>   Table A rows.

I would start with the code that updates table B. is this done in a trigger, c#/java... code, or SP ?

Need existing code and schema to better help you.

Comment: We are working on PHP/MySQL everything done in php mysql itself.. Where Table B data gets updated by Table A data and Row counts..